# Django how to reverse a OneToOne relationship models.CASCADE

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class BorrowDetails(models.Model):
    BorrowDate = models.DateField()

class Book(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    BorrowDetails = models.OneToOneField(BorrowDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Is there a way to make it so that when a Book gets deleted then BorrowDetails gets deleted instead of the other way around? I don't want to assign the OneToOne in the BorrowDetails as I want the JSON for my Book to contain BorrowDetails

Comment: You can make use a signal, although signals are often an anti-pattern.

Comment: However you can still serialize a model and follow a relation in reverse, so I'm not sure that you make the design based on the correct arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [*signals* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). This is a mechanism to register a handler when a certain event happens, for example deleting a book:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from appname.models import Book

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Book)
def delete_book(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.BorrowDetails.delete()
```

But [signals are often considered an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/): they make it less predictable what will happen, often there are ways to circumvent the signals, and often problems can be solved in a more reliable and elegant way. If you for example work with the *Django REST Framework (DRF)*, you can define a serializer to effectively serialize the relation in the other direction, and then defining the `OneToOneField` in the other way is not a problem. For more information, see the [*Serializer relations* section of the DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

Comment: Decided to use signals for now as a temporary setup, and `pre_delete` gives a strange infinite recursion error while `post_delete` works as expected

Comment: @meghidey: sorry yes, `post_save`, `pre_save` will indeed recurse, since it will the trigger the `CASCADE`, so it will delete a `Book` because it deletes that book.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Signals seem to be the only way to go here, if one cannot define the relation on "the other side", right? For example, if the related model is defined in an external library?

Comment: @Hafnernuss: you can still add that, with `.contribute_to_class`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L888 this is in essence what happens with all the fields you define on a model.

Comment: If i read that correctly, that would mean implementing a custom ForeignKey field, which actually adds the FK to the "Target" model, right? And I'd have to use `contribute_to_related_class` right? But wouldnt that cause migrations on the related model (app)?

Comment: @Hafnernuss: yes, it will then create a migration file, and thus you can add a foreign key that way to a "foreign model".

Comment: Yes, but the migration will be created in the library, something that typically isn't wanted. Seems like signals are the only way then.